# flask restplus works in my local docker images but doesn't in azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, flask, flask-restplus

i did my flask application using flask restplus,  i try it locally using runserver.py and i can see my swagger api,   i put it on a docker container exposing port 80   and i run it with -p 4000:80  and also works fine,  but when i send the image to the container registry in azure, and put it on my webaplication all the other end points works,  but just the root that points to the swagger api page doesnt =( i get the message

```
No spec provided.
```

is there some other things that i need to expose? like another port? or might be an azure security?  maybe flask restplus needs to get something from internet? like a CND website to get the colors or svgs?

thanks guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No spec provided" error when trying to deliver swagger.json over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292579/no-spec-provided-error-when-trying-to-deliver-swagger-json-over-https)

Comment: seems that is because i was adding an / at the end of the url =(,     with the URL paths,  i think is been different if you do:       path/to/       than  path/to      with no trailing slash.